# PHP mySQL - how to get 5 of each type in table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mySql table:

```
Game   |  Type  
-------|----------
Game1  | Action  
Game2  | Roleplay  
Game3  | Action  
Game4  | Sandbox  
Game5  | Sandbox  
Game6  | Roleplay  
Game7  | Fighting  
Game8  | Fighting  
Game9  | Adventure  
Game10 | Adventure 
Game11 | Action  
Game12 | Roleplay  
Game13 | Action  
Game14 | Sandbox  
Game15 | Sandbox  
Game16 | Roleplay  
Game17 | Fighting  
Game18 | Fighting  
Game19 | Adventure  
Game20 | Adventure
Game21 | Roleplay  
Game23 | Action  
Game24 | Sandbox  
Game25 | Sandbox
```

How can I order these into into 5 groups of 5, like this:

```
Game1  | Action  
-------|----------
Game3  | Action  
Game7  | Action  
Game11 | Action  
Game13 | Action  
Game2  | Roleplay  
Game6  | Roleplay  
Game9  | Roleplay   
Game12 | Roleplay  
Game19 | Roleplay    
Game7  | Fighting
Game8  | Fighting  
Game17 | Fighting   
Game18 | Fighting  
Game18 | Fighting     
Game9  | Adventure  
Game10 | Adventure  
Game19 | Adventure   
Game20 | Adventure 
Game20 | Adventure    
Game4  | Sandbox 
Game5  | Sandbox  
Game14 | Sandbox   
Game15 | Sandbox  
Game15 | Sandbox
```

Preferably, it will work with 1 sql and `mysqli_query`.

Comment: What is your MySQL **Server** version ?

Comment: 10.1.30-MariaDB-1~xenial - mariadb.org binary distribution

Comment: Please provide a desired result that is consistent with the sample data.

Comment: It is a Window function problem (newer versions support it). But it can be done using user-defined variables also. Please update your question such that your sample data matches with expected output

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT Action FROM table. It will loop through the actions and within the loop you will need SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 5. I cannot come up with an idea to make it all with just 1 query

Answer (score 0):

In legacy MariaDB window function such `ROW_NUMBER` are not supported, so the problem can be solved using variables:

```
SET @q = 0;
SET @type = '';

SELECT Game, Type FROM (
  SELECT Games.*, @q:=CASE WHEN @type = Games.type then @q+1 ELSE 1 END Number, @type:=Games.type
  FROM Games
  ORDER BY Games.Type, Games.Game
) R
WHERE Number < 6;
```

[MariaDB fiddle](https://sqlize.online/sql/mariadb/de716c1b586014deb57c920f7a6fd9c7/)

Answer (score -1):

```
$query_a = "SELECT DISTINCT Action FROM table";
$result_a = mysqli_query($connection, $query_a) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
while($row_a = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_a) { 
    $query_g = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE Action = ".$row_a['Action']." LIMIT 5";
    $result_g = mysqli_query($connection, $query_g) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
    while($row_g = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_g) { 
        echo $row_g['Game'].' '.row_g['Action'].'<br>';
    } result_g -> close();  
}$result_a -> close();
```

Two queries.

Comment: What if another user adds a new action between the execution of the first query, and the execution of the second?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about this, but the last Action entry will fall at the bottom of the table therefore the first query will go through every single distinct existing action.